# How to organize interaction between .NET online MMORPG server and client

Tags: .net, client-server, mmo

I'm currently considering building a simple MMORPG.

The idea is to have a .NET server and downloadable client app.

What's easiest yet efficient way to organize client-server interaction?

I thought of a webservice, but it looks pretty inefficient as long as clients have to perform many game actions quickly (e.g. movement, picking up items, attacking other players, etc)

Creating a custom communication protocol is a very complex task.

Do any off-the-shelf solutions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very experienced in development of communication protocols for games, however, since no answers appeared here for some time I can share my opinion with you.

**Communication protocol choice**

I suppose you can combine two methods of communication:

- **UDP** for information that needs to be received quickly and which you send very often, so a loss of a single packet won't be a problem. You can use UDP to send information like: player position of movements for animations
- **TCP** for information that is important and that you have to be sure is received, like an object picked up, player hitting other player, quest start/completion etc.

**Choosing data to be sent**

Another important thing to remember is to ***send minimum amount of data***, so rather send only X;Y for player position than serialize the whole player object ;).

Designing the communication API and splitting responsibilities between server and clients can depend on few things, like game type and safety vs performance: doing more calculations and putting more responsibilities on the client side can result in better performance of the server, but decreses safety of a game, because it's then more likely someone will try to cheat).

Some sample links just to get you started:

- [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)
- [Best Practices for System.Net classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhzezf6d.aspx)
- [TcpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)
- [UdpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx)
- [Network Programming Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890485.aspx) (there is a sample using Socket class)